# Yii2 : Getting unknown property when using findBySql

Tags: mysql, sql, web, frameworks, yii2

i'm using findBySql() to get data from database,
i want to show the data in view with table.

This is code on my controller :

```
$sql = "SELECT presensi.presensi_tanggal 'tanggal', sum(if( hadir.keteranganhadir_id='1',1,0)) 'hadir', sum(if( hadir.keteranganhadir_id='2',1,0)) 'tidak_hadir', count(*) 'total' FROM hadir, keteranganhadir, presensi where hadir.keteranganhadir_id = keteranganhadir.keteranganhadir_id and hadir.presensi_id = presensi.presensi_id group by presensi.presensi_tanggal";

    $model = Hadir::findBySql($sql)->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'hadir' => $model,
    ]);
```

So, i want to show 'tanggal', 'hadir', 'tidak hadir' and 'total'.

In my view,

```
<?php foreach($hadir as $data): ?>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="tbl_column_name"><?=$data->tanggal;?></td>
        <td class="tbl_column_name"><?=$data->hadir;?></td>
        <td class="tbl_column_name"><?=$data->tidak_hadir;?></td>
        <td class="tbl_column_name"><?=$data->total;?></td>
        <td><a href="kehadiran/view?id=1">Lihat</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But, i got error like this
**Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: common\models\data\Hadir::tanggal**.
So, what is the problem and what should i do? Thank you~

[EDITED]

Hadir Model :

```
    <?php
namespace common\models\data;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "hadir".
 *
 * @property integer $ADIKBINAAN_ID
 * @property integer $PRESENSI_ID
 * @property integer $KETERANGANHADIR_ID
 *
 * @property Adikbinaan $aDIKBINAAN
 * @property Presensi $pRESENSI
 */
class Hadir extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'hadir';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['ADIKBINAAN_ID', 'PRESENSI_ID', 'KETERANGANHADIR_ID'], 'required'],
            [['ADIKBINAAN_ID', 'PRESENSI_ID', 'KETERANGANHADIR_ID'], 'integer']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'ADIKBINAAN_ID' => 'Adikbinaan  ID',
            'PRESENSI_ID' => 'Presensi  ID',
            'KETERANGANHADIR_ID' => 'Keteranganhadir  ID',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getADIKBINAAN()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Adikbinaan::className(), ['ADIKBINAAN_ID' => 'ADIKBINAAN_ID']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPRESENSI()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Presensi::className(), ['PRESENSI_ID' => 'PRESENSI_ID']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your raw sql returning results?

Comment: yes, it is. in mysql, the query is returning results

Comment: Can you show your model class?

Comment: i add model class in question

Comment: Try to declare a public variable/property in your Hadir model: `public $tanggal` just at the start of model declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the attributes that are extracted from the returned rows are only the columns that can be found in the table.

I get the impression from your code that those fields are not. To fix this you should probably override the `attributes()`-function and declare those properties as valid:

```
public function attributes()
{
    return array_merge(parent::attributes(), ['tanggal', 'hadir', 'tidak_hadir', 'total']);
}
```

This should instruct the `populateRecord()`-function to also fill those.

Comment: should i add this in model ?